# vim: displaying submatch contents and the unnamed register in a substitution

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I've got multiple commands in a command line that builds a text string in the unnamed register @".  Then I have a substitute that captures a couple of atoms. Finally, I need to replace a pattern with the two submatches (\1 and \2) AND the @".

I cannot get the @" reg to display its contents AFTER first displaying the submatches.  I can display the @" prior to displaying the submatches.  For ex:

```
multi-commands | @"=textString | 'a,'bs/(atom1)(atom2)/\1\2 "displays perfectly
```

Or,

```
multi-commands | @"=textString | 'a,'bs/(atom1)(atom2)/\=@" "displays 'textString' perfectly
```

But,

```
multi-commands | @"=textString | 'a,'bs/(atom1)(atom2)/\1\2@"
multi-commands | @"=textString | 'a,'bs/(atom1)(atom2)/\1\2\@"
multi-commands | @"=textString | 'a,'bs/(atom1)(atom2)/\1\2\=@"
```

All fail to display the register contents of 'textString' and instead show '@"'

Does anyone know why that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of `\=` needs to be first item in a replacement.

You should use the following:

```
:'a,'bs/(atom1)(atom2)/\=submatch(1).submatch(2).@"
```

Comment: See also `:help sub-replace-\=` and `:help submatch`.

Comment: The help states: "a substitute() function inside
the expression cannot use "\=" for the substitute string."  I guess the short syntax of \1\2 is effectively doing that, which causes the /1/2.@" syntax to fail(?).  Regardless, thank you for your accurate help.